# How to call a Javascript function in Blazor server-side?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Javascript function in an external js file:

```
$(function () {
    $("#form-total").steps({
        //code removed
    });
});
```

I added the script to the main `_Host.cshtml` file.

When is this function called? On page load?

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function on the client (browser) from the server?

Comment: [Call Javascript function using JS interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Kindly flow this link.